# I am trying to set the text of a textView, however, whenever I do so, an error pops up

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I have a textView, but when I try to set it's value to an EditText, it says that the textView is final. When I change it to not be final, an error occurs stating that textView needs an int. Why would it do this, and how can I change it so that it will take in the text in EditText? Here is the code for the class where I am trying to set the value for the textView:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3;
}
}
```

Here is the xml activity where textView is created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.kalyannath.cancerapp.cancerapp20.MainScreen"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_screen">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="User Control Panel"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Your Cancer:"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code where the EditText is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.kalyannath.cancerapp.cancerapp20.GetInformation"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_get_information">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Please fill out the information below"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Which type of cancer do you have?"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="What is your age?"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Male or female?"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Which stage?"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Which receptor does your cancer act on? You mau need to ask your doctor"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is happening? Thanks!

Comment: where is your setText() code?

Comment: R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3; what does this means

Comment: use setText() method for setting text to TextView.

Comment: There are answers. Accept if it works

Comment: No, it does not work. The app crashes

Answer (score 0):

```
R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3;
```

If this is how you are setting the text of EditText in TextView, it is wrong.

To set text in TextView you have to use setText() method.

example;

```
//Refering to you edit text
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
//Refering to you TextView
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

//getting text from edit text
String editTextString = editText.getText();
//setting text to TextView
textView.setText(editTextString);
```

try this, this will work. 
and I recommend you to learn the basics of android/java programming.

Comment: see the OP is trying to set Text in his TextView like `R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3;` thats what I mean

Comment: nope, I asking to OP, I want to make sure that he is trying to set the text through the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
Textview textView12=(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.textView12);

EditText editText3=(EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.editText3);
```

here is your answer

```
String text=textView12.getText().toString();

editText3.setText(text);
```

or

```
editText3.setText(textView12.getText().toString());
```

i hope this solves your problem

Comment: `editText3=textView12.getText().toString();` what is this ?

Comment: String text=textView12.getText().toString(); editText3.setText(text);

Comment: thats not what you posted there

Comment: When I use the code above, the app works, until I press the button which takes me to the MainScreen acitivity. The program crashes. I suspect that it has to do something with the local variable being created and setting them to their respective values when the onCreate() method is called. How can I fix this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: why is editText3 being set to whatever textView12 has? I am trying to get textView12 to read the user input from editText3, which is in another xml.

Comment: can you put your error log ,it will be helpful to know why the app getting crashed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3;
```

Use

```
Textview tv =(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.textView12); 
EditText et =(EditText) findviewbyid(R.id.editText3);
```

to set content of edittext to textview use

```
tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
```

This Might Help You Out...

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

you are doing the set of text wrongly

```
 R.id.textView12 = R.id.editText3;
```

this is trying to manipulate the ids in the android app,

### QuickFix

instead use:

```
textView.setText(editTextString);
```